Azure Blob Storage Error: Missing subscription configuration in .NET Aspire
I'm trying to run Azure blob storage by Aspire
so I read this document
so I created Aspire AppHost and added this code to Program.cs file
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var blobs = builder.AddAzureStorage("storage")
    .AddBlobs("blobs");

builder.Build().Run();

this is my solution files

and I run the project
Expectation: The project creates an azurite container in the docker
Problem: no container running in the docker and I don't know why its two projects are running in the picture and it gives me Error: Missing subscription configuration

and this is the project log file


just run it as Emulator it will fix
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var blobs = builder.AddAzureStorage("storage")
    .RunAsEmulator()
    .AddBlobs("blobs");

builder. Build().Run();

and also if you want to have DataVolume use lambda expression for RunAsEmulator
var blobs = builder.AddAzureStorage("storage")
        .RunAsEmulator(e=>e.WithDataVolume())
        .AddBlobs("blobs");


Right! If you don't RunAsEmulator then it'll ask you for an azure subscription to create one.
